# I can't fix Heroku "Could not find a required file, Name: index.html" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am new to Heroku. I tried deleting .gitignore and rearranging my files around, but it still gives me that error. I have a program with React.js as the front end and Node.js as the backend. I need this to deploy to Heroku. The image below shows the error I get.

[image: Image of the error I get]

In my Node.js code, I tried specifying where Heroku should in "client" folder for the "index.html" file.  This is my node.js code:

```js
//code based off of:
// https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();
const apiKey = 'api-key-here';

// Have Node serve the files for our built React app
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});



app.get('/getCoinInfo', (req, res) => {
  console.log('The request has been received!!')
  request(
    { url: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=' + apiKey},
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }
      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    }
  )
});

// All other GET requests not handled before will return our React app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```

Also here is my file structure.

[image]

What are your suggestions to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` file appears to be in `client/public`, not in `client/build`.

But if there is another `index.html` in `build`, you could try using `join` instead of `resolve`:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));
```